# Chrome Stroge Sync Return Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, synchronization, storage

```js
//Options
var useProxy = false;
var useIPDebugger = false;
var useUserAgentT = false;
var useBlockJS = false;
var useBlockCSS = false;

//Load Options
chrome.storage.sync.get("useUserAgent", 
  function(val) {
    alert(val.useUserAgent); //return True
    useUserAgentT = val.useUserAgent; //marking
  }
);
alert(useUserAgentT); //but return False
```

`val.useUserAgent` is returning True but `useUserAgentT = val.useUserAgent;` and `alert(useUserAgentT);` are returning false :/

More detail for files.

options.js

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var isCheckedProxy = false;
 var isCheckedIPDebug = false;
 var isCheckedUserAgent = false;
 var isCheckedJS = false;
 var isCheckedCSS = false;
 $('#isCheckedProxy').on('change', function(){
  if(this.checked) {isCheckedProxy = true; chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: String("true")});} else {isCheckedProxy = false; chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: String("false")});}
  save_options();
 });
 $('#isCheckedIPDebug').on('change', function(){
  if(this.checked) {isCheckedIPDebug = true;} else {isCheckedIPDebug = false;}
  save_options();
 });
 $('#isCheckedUserAgent').on('change', function(){
  if(this.checked) {isCheckedUserAgent = true;} else {isCheckedUserAgent = false;}
  save_options();
 });
 $('#isCheckedJS').on('change', function(){
  if(this.checked) {isCheckedJS = true;} else {isCheckedJS = false;}
  save_options();
 });
 $('#isCheckedCSS').on('change', function(){
  if(this.checked) {isCheckedCSS = true;} else {isCheckedCSS = false;}
  save_options();
 });
 //Kaydet
 function save_options() {
  chrome.storage.sync.set({
   isCheckedProxy: isCheckedProxy,
   isCheckedIPDebug: isCheckedIPDebug,
   isCheckedUserAgent: isCheckedUserAgent,
   useUserAgent: isCheckedUserAgent, //this is useUserAgent setting.
   isCheckedJS: isCheckedJS,
   isCheckedCSS: isCheckedCSS
  }, function() {
   //alert("saved.");
  });
 }
 //Yükle
 function restore_options() {
    chrome.storage.sync.get({
   isCheckedProxy: isCheckedProxy,
   isCheckedIPDebug: isCheckedIPDebug,
   isCheckedUserAgent: isCheckedUserAgent,
   isCheckedJS: isCheckedJS,
   isCheckedCSS: isCheckedCSS
    }, function(items) {
   $('#isCheckedProxy').attr( 'checked', items.isCheckedProxy );
   isCheckedProxy = items.isCheckedProxy;
   if(items.isCheckedProxy == true) {chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: String("true")});} else {chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: String("false")});}
   $('#isCheckedIPDebug').attr( 'checked', items.isCheckedIPDebug );
   isCheckedIPDebug = items.isCheckedIPDebug;
   $('#isCheckedUserAgent').attr( 'checked', items.isCheckedUserAgent );
   isCheckedUserAgent = items.isCheckedUserAgent;
   $('#isCheckedJS').attr( 'checked', items.isCheckedJS );
   isCheckedJS = items.isCheckedJS;
   $('#isCheckedCSS').attr( 'checked', items.isCheckedCSS );
   isCheckedCSS = items.isCheckedCSS;
    });
 }
 restore_options();
});
```

background.js

```js
//Options
var useProxy = false;
var useIPDebugger = false;
var useUserAgentT = false;
var useBlockJS = false;
var useBlockCSS = false;

//Load Options
chrome.storage.sync.get("useUserAgent", 
  function(val) {
    useUserAgentT = val.useUserAgent;
 //alert(val.useUserAgent);
  }
);

alert(useUserAgentT);

 var items = ["Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.1", "Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Comodo_Dragon/16.1.1.0 Chrome/16.0.912.63 Safari/535.7", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; BecomeBot/3.0; MSIE 6.0 compatible; +http://www.become.com/site_owners.html)", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20121202 Firefox/17.0 Iceweasel/17.0.1", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.23; Macintosh; PPC) Escape 5.1.8", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; IBrowse 3.0; AmigaOS4.0)", "Opera/9.80 (X11; Linux i686; Ubuntu/14.10) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.16"];
 chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(function(details){
   var headers = details.requestHeaders,
   blockingResponse = {};
   for( var i = 0, l = headers.length; i < l; ++i ) {
  if( headers[i].name == 'User-Agent' ) {
    headers[i].value = items[Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length)];
    console.log(headers[i].value);
    break;
  }
   }
   blockingResponse.requestHeaders = headers;
   return blockingResponse;
 },
 {urls: [ "<all_urls>" ]},['requestHeaders','blocking']);
}
//Set Status
chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: String("unknown")});
```

Answer (score 0):

That's due to asynchronous nature of the API. `chrome.storage.sync.get()` takes your callback (`function (val) { /* ... */ }`) and returns immediately. The callback gets executed at some moment later. So, the *actual* order of execution is:

```
var useUserAgentT = false;

/* ... */

alert(useUserAgentT);

/* some time later in the callback */

useUserAgentT = val.useUserAgent.
```